# Non-Blocking MySQL queries in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I wrote a non-blocking MySQL interface for java (wrapped around the standard mysql java connector).

I think the code to use it looks a bit ugly however...

```
db.rawQuery(queries.someAlreadyPreparedStatement, (new Callback(){
    public void result(ResultSet result){
        while (result.next()) {
            //Handle each row from the result and do any processing
    }
}));
```

How could this be improved? Is this as good as it gets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as good as it gets in Java. The idea of callbacks are very popular, and are the foundation of functional languages. Even Javascript offers a cleaner approach, as [JQuery shows](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Unfortunately for Java, anonymous inner classes (as you have) are the shortest way to create a function like this.